# php variable not getting substituted with value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an issue. I am sending data from javascript to PHP. In PHP the value is extracted into a variable. This value has to be substituted in the create statement. It is not getting substituted. On echoing the php variable is being read. why isn't it getting passed to the create statement? The relevant code snippets are below:

AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "createTableInDB.php",
    data: 'pTblName=' + filename,
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

When I check in PHP, the filename is taken into the variable correctly.

PHP code:

```
$username="root";
$pass="";

try {
    $db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", $username, $pass);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES , false);

    $tblName = stripcslashes($_POST['pTblName']);

    $sql = "CREATE table If Not Exists $tblName (
            Sl_No varchar(4) Primary Key,
            E_Name varchar(100) not null,
            EXP varchar(10) not null);";

    $db_conn->exec($sql);

    echo("Created Table");


    }
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Can anyone guide me where I am wrong? I am not getting any error messages. The page just reloads and everything resets.

The function calling the function with ajax:
    function extractName(){
        fullPath = document.getElementById('testInputFile').value;

```
    if (fullPath) {
        var startIndex = (fullPath.indexOf('\\') >= 0 ? fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') : fullPath.lastIndexOf('/'));
        filename = fullPath.substring(startIndex);
        if (filename.indexOf('\\') === 0 || filename.indexOf('/') === 0) {
            // filename = filename.substring(1);
            filename = filename.substring(1, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
        }

        //console.log(filename);
        createTableInDB(filename);
    //  Excel = readExcelFile(fullpath);
    }
   }
```

This function is called in the submit button of the html form

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Are you sure that the query is executed without any error ?

Comment: May i know the output of  echo("Created Table");?

Comment: @Nimeshka The query is not executed at all

Comment: Could you edit your question and show us the entire function that calls your ajax? I kinda have a feeling you're not using `preventDefault()`

Comment: @AyyappanSekar There is no output at all. Nothing is returned to my success function

Comment: @icecub this is the entire ajax function. I am just extracting the file name from a html form and passing that to PHP as I want a table created in that name

Comment: @PallaviPrasad you mentioned that you get the file name in the variable in php script. So I guess you have no issue with the ajax function or passing the parameter to the phs script.  I suggest you to hard code the table name in the query and run the same script. If it still doesn't create the table, then there could be a issue in your database.

Comment: I know. But what's calling it? I assume you have something like `$("#yourForm").on("submit", function(){`

Comment: The filename is sent correctly. When I `echo` it in PHP, it is returned correctly.

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal I want the table name to be dynamic. Hence this code

Comment: @PallaviPrasad I know. This is just to see where the issue lies :) If it creates the table when you hardcode it, then you will know that you have no problem in your query.

Comment: @PallaviPrasad Did you specify datatype of your posting data ? like datatype:'text'

Comment: There is a button which when clicked, extracts uploaded filename and passes it to the function with the ajax call. I will edit my post adding this code

Comment: @SaadSuri You don't have to provide the datatype ( If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response)

Comment: We need the full `createTableInDB()` function code. Not the code that calls that function.

Comment: @PallaviPrasad:  I think there is no issue with the ajax call and php script as well. I tested both and i am able to they are working fine. Can you try executing a select statement and see the database connection is properly working?

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal Thanks. I tried with hardcoded table name and the query is working perfectly. It is only when I make it dynamic that there is an issue

Comment: @AyyappanSekar I think it's just as I expected from the start. He's not using `preventDefault()`. The form is being submitted normally.

Comment: @icecub I have posted the entire `createTableInDB()`. That is all there is in the function. It has the ajax call only at present.

Comment: Yes. And that's exactly what's going wrong. You're not preventing the form from being submitted normally. So Ajax is sending it, but your browser is browsing towards the PHP just as well. You need to use `preventDefault()` to stop this.

Comment: @icecub Where do I add the `preventDefault()`?

Comment: @PallaviPrasad can you post your environment details? I tried your code and it works perfectly in my pc :)

Comment: I am using chrome and xampp server

Comment: @PallaviPrasad: If you send the filename to php script by ajax call, dont use submit button in form. Use a normal button instead and call your createTableInDB() function on click of that button.

Comment: Give your form a unique id like `<form id="someid">` Then use code like this: `$("#someid").on("submit", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); // ajax call here });`

Comment: This comment thread is getting longer. What is the php version?

Comment: I agree. The comment section is getting to long. You know what? Put your entire code into a ZIP archive. Upload it here: http://home.icecub.nl/PairProgramming/ (read the explanation!). Then comment the invite URL here. We'll be able to join you there and work on your code together.

Comment: @icecub Done. By the way. I changed the code the what you suggested. Still not working

Comment: @PallaviPrasad Read my previous comment. Upload your code to my server. All of it. Because we won't be able to figure out what's going on like this.

Comment: @PallaviPrasad Feel free to remove any sensitive information like database passwords first of course. We don't need those.

Comment: @icecub the link: http://home.icecub.nl/PairProgramming/project.php?id=298347445#&togetherjs=eHRd93gVdf

Comment: @PallaviPrasad I'm there. You can chat with me on the right

Comment: @PallaviPrasad If you accidently closed the page, just click on the link you just gave me here. It will get you back in

Comment: @PallaviPrasad I need you to be there as well. I can't fix the issue without you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved. In the PHP code, I just added the following lines:

```
$sql="use test";
$db_conn->exec($sql);
```

I added this before the create statement and it is working.

Everyone's help and guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "createTableInDB.php",
    data: 'pTblName=' + filename,
    success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
    }
});
```

And your php cod edit this line :

```
$tblName = stripcslashes($_GET['pTblName']);
```